# Issue with position fixed in css

Tags: html, css

I have navigation bar at the top and i have fixed its position But, some of the body content is lying beneath the fixed navigation bar.means it is hidden by fixed navigation bar How to fix this problem.

Comment: Please provide us with relevant coding.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) you find all explanations for the property `z-index` which sets the order you want to display blocks of the page.

Assuming you have `z-index: 1;` set to the navigation bar, items hidden by it should have a greater z-index than the navigation bar itself (eg. >1 in this case)

Comment: navigation bar and content below it is overlapping after i fixed the position of nav bar. I just wanted to get rid of this overlapping

Comment: the content below is overlapping the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

I might not be correct but I think I understand what you are talking about. 
The `body` contents must be relative positioned and fixed positioned navigation bar doesn't stay in same flow.

just wrap all other content in one `div` and add `margin-top` to div equal to the height of your navigation bar. If its not wrapped you can also try adding `margin-top` to `body` tag.

Note: for clear understanding of your problem please provide some code.